# Will affect on performance the creating new schema at every functional call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

Based on my requirement I have to create new `schema` at every function call.

That actually works, but I am worry about its performance.

**My code:**

```
   app.post('/',  (req, res)=> {

      const {query, data} = req.body;

      doOperations(data, 'multiValueSearch', docs => {
        
            const RootQueryType = GraphQLObjectType({
                name: "RootQuery",
                fields: {   
                    users: {
                        type: GraphQLList(UserType),
                        resolve: ()=> docs
                    }
                }
    
            });
        
            const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
                query: RootQueryType
            });
       
            graphql(schema, query).then(result => res.json(result)));
        
       });

   });
```

The function `doOperations` is involved at any time users search their friends.
So in every search this `doOperations` gets called.

**Is this a problem or is not concern will no affect on graphql performance ?**

**Why I am have to do this ?** because the `docs` returns based on `data` I am passing to db.

Comment: Where does `query` come from? Where does `callback` come from? How is `doOperations` defined (and what does it do)? And where is all of this code (the `doOperations()` call) located? It seems weirdly inverted - normally operations are done from within a resolver function of a schema.

Comment: @Bergi, query comes from client using `req.body.query` and I call `doOperations` inside `app.get('/', (req, res) => {doOperations()})`;

Comment: ... or how is used? why? show/describe context ... looks strange ... graphql response without graphql server?

Comment: @xadm, I just posted a part of my code to avoid a huge here as we dont need. I just need to know is this way a bad way or a good way.

Comment: @Muhammad Do you have other graphql endpoints besides that? Does your schema really have only a single top-level field?

Comment: still strange and seems very limiting, no relations, other types

Comment: @Bergi, Yeah I have one single top level field as of now, and please see I have edited my code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is `data` used for? It *really* should be an argument of your `users` field in the schema.

Comment: `data` is an array I pass it to mongodb for filtering.

Comment: if works, ok ... but it can be only a PoC... don't go this way further ... resolver is for db operations, one for one type/field, it's server role to compose result from different/many resolvers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I am have to do this? because the docs returns based on data I am passing to db.

No, that's not a reason to create a new schema on every call.

You should create a static schema that uses a resolver which takes the `docs` from the `rootvalue` that can be passed with every graphql query `execute()`ion.

---

In your case, you actually don't even need that. Instead of running `doOperations` for the whole endpoint, you should run it inside the resolver that produces the users and make `data` an argument:

```
const RootQueryType = GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "RootQuery",
    fields: {   
        users: {
            type: GraphQLList(UserType),
            args: {
                filter: {
                    type: GraphQLList(ConditionType),
                },
            },
            resolve(_, {filter}) {
                return doOperations(filter, 'multiValueSearch');
            }
        }
    }

});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQueryType
});


app.post('/',  (req, res)=> {
    const {query, variables} = req.body;
    graphql(schema, query, null, {}, variables).then(result => {
        res.json(result);
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: 'A problem occurred.'});
    });
});
```

Comment: please check once again as I have added some code snipt, may give more sence

Comment: data is an array I pass it to mongodb for filtering

Comment: @Muhammad An array of what?

Comment: an array of objects

Comment: `data` passed to `users.find({$or: data}).toArray( (err, docs))`, of mongodb drive of nodejs

Comment: If it's a filter for the users, it should *definitely* be an argument of the `users` field. Define an input type for it.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please let me know why you are using `Promise` here ?

Comment: Because your `doOperations` function takes a callback to which it passes the result, so I'm promisifying it and make `resolve` return a promise. Since you control the implementation of `doOperations` and mongodb natively supports promises, you really should drop the callback and simply make it return a promise for the documents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224157/discussion-between-muhammad-and-bergi).